# Were any rebel ships destroyed/critically damaged during the assault on Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

I'm splitting the battle for Scarif into 2 parts: 1.) The assault on the planet and the shield itself and 2.) The escape.

For 2. it was quite easily seen how many ships (not fighters!) were damaged / destroyed (and it was QUITE a few). What I'm wondering about though is during the assault (1.)) on Scarif....when the empire in essence had double the units available. Were they able to critically damage or even destroy ANY ship at all?

Comment: Are you asking whether the Empire was able to actively  disable or destroy rebel ships until the shield gate was disabled (via critically damaging a corvette)? If so,  capital ships only or fighters/bombers included? Inside or outside the shield?

Comment: What do you mean by "the escape"? Did anyone actually escape Scarif? I assumed everyone inside the shield gate was destroyed by the Death Star.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking yepp or severly damaged capital ships (some dont count corvettes as capital ships thus had to differentate by saying "aside from fighters"). And as far as I'm aware only fighters made it into the shield (and small smuggler ships of fighter size).

Answer (score 2):

1. An unnamed member of "Blue Squadron" (an X-Wing) was destroyed when it didn't get through the shield gate in time. It could be argued that it was an accident or a "self-destruction", but it was definitely caused by the closing of the gate, so technically the Empire did it.
2. "Red 5" (also an X-Wing) was destroyed by a Tie Fighter around 1:45. He says something like "They're all over me" and then gets blown up.

Comment: The question seems to make a distinction between fighters and ships and they’re asking about the latter whereas your answer covers the former. If I’m reading it correctly anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot yepp  I menat non fighters (as stated)  as we see the fighters quite well when they blew up. But aside from the "escape" aka jump into hyperspace, I didnt notice any rebel ship get damaged (aside from the suicide run of the hammerhead)

Comment: @Thomas so you know that the Hammerhead was destroyed. And that fighters were destroyed. What are you asking? Is there any answer that would satisfy you?

Comment: @LevenTrek as I mentioned it is if during the battle captial ships were destroyed or badly damaged on the rebel side (the hammerhead would count there even though a suicide run. What I'm after is details on the battle as I still find it wow that 2 SDs + a shield bases tie fighters did so little damage while a single SD almost barehandedly wiped the floor with everything the rebels got) thus looking to see if I overlooked anything during the battle or not